# Kafka version supported for versions for SCDF 1.3

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am using the local server version 1.3 for SCDF, and have kafka version kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0 running. The application I am currently using to test the flow is the time-source-kafka build locally (maven://org.springframework.cloud.stream.app:time-source-kafka:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT) just cloned from git.

The simple time|log stream deploys fine, and connects to kafka client fine, but then starts showing:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Magic v1 does not support record headers

So, I guess what version of Kafka is supported?, and recommended?, and should I be using the version 2.0 snapshot of the app with version 1.3 of the server?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of SCDF is not so important but the 2.0 apps are intended to be used with Kafka 0.11 or higher.

Use the 1.3.x apps with an older Kafka broker.

Comment: thanks Gary! yes, I just now switched to 0.11 and it started working...